# Using std::move, and preventing further use of the data

Tags: c++11, move

I have been using c++11 for some time but I always avoided using std::move because I was scared that, while reading a library where the user does not have the access to the code, it would try to use the variable after I move it.

So basically something like

```
void loadData(std::string&& path);
```

Would not be enough to make the user understand that it will be moved.
Is it expected that the use of && would imply that the data will be moved. I know that comments can be used to explain the use case, but a lot of people dont pay attention to that.

Is it safe to assume that when you see a && the data will be moved, or when should I use std::move and how to make it explicit from the signature.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it expected that the use of && would imply that the data will be moved.

Generally speaking yes. A user cannot call `loadData` with an lvalue. They must provide a prvalue or an xvalue. So if you have a variable to pass, your code would generally look like `loadData(std::move(variable))`, which is a pretty good indicator of what you're doing from your side. `forward`ing could also be employed, but you'd still see it at the call site.

Indeed, generally speaking it is *extremely rude* to move from a parameter which is *not* an rvalue reference.